# How to iterate through all text video sound and image files by content type regardless extension

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to use 4 for cycles for each category text (included code script and src files), video, sound and image files.

Checking the extesion explicitly to perform the check with something like

```
for i in *.ext1 *.ext2 *.ext...
```

requires me to specify every extension possible for each category, and I'm looking for an alternative way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no alternative way. Remember that on *nix systems, so probably on whatever operating system you are using, extensions are generally optional and decorative. This means that you can have files with no extension at all:

```
$ ls
foo1  foo10  foo2  foo3  foo4  foo5  foo6  foo7  foo8  foo9

$ for file in *; do file "$file"; done
foo1: PNG image data, 25 x 25, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
foo10: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 8 bit, mono 22050 Hz
foo2: GIF image data, version 89a, 500 x 225
foo3: HTML document, Unicode text, UTF-8 text, with very long lines (1207)
foo4: MPEG sequence, v2, program multiplex
foo5: Ogg data, Vorbis audio, stereo, 44100 Hz, ~128000 bps
foo6: Audio file with ID3 version 2.2.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 160 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo
foo7: ISO Media, Apple QuickTime movie, Apple QuickTime (.MOV/QT)
foo8: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 640 x 480, 30.00 fps, video: FFMpeg MPEG-4, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (mono, 44100 Hz)
foo9: ASCII text
```

Therefore, the only option would be to write a program that extracts the file type and then categorizes it into one of the categories you mentioned. If such a tool exists, I am not aware of it.

If you do want to write one, you could start by using `file` as above, then define what file types should go under which category and take it from there. But there won't be a shell-native approach that does this for you.

Comment: +1.   `file`'s `--mime-type` option would be useful for this.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @terdon's answer (in short: "use file"), you could do something like this:

```
file --mime-type * |
  awk -F': ' '$2 ~ /^video/ { system("process_video_file.sh " $1) ; next };
              $2 ~ /^image/ { system("process_image_file.sh " $1) ; next };
              $2 ~ /^audio/ { system("process_audio_file.sh " $1) ; next };
              { print "$1: unknown file type $2" }'
```

You would, of course, have to write the `process_video_file.sh`, `process_image_file.sh`, and `process_audio_file.sh` scripts.

Note: this will break on filenames containing newlines or the sequence `:`  (colon and a space), which is unlikely but not impossible to encounter.

Alternatively, you could do something similar in shell:

```
while read -r f ft ; do
  case "$ft" in
    video*) process_video_file "$f" ;;
    image*) process_image_file "$f" ;;
    audio*) process_audio_file "$f" ;;
    *) echo "$f: unknown file type $ft" ;;
  esac
done < <(file --mime-type * | sed -e 's/: /\t/')
```

Because this is in a shell script, you could write "process_(video|image|audio)_file" as separate shell scripts or as shell functions defined in the same script. You could even in-line them into the case statements (but that way leads towards unreadable/unmaintainable code if there's more than just a few statements per case).

Note: this will break on filenames with spaces, newlines, tabs or the same colon and space sequence as the awk version.

It wouldn't be hard to rewrite this (or the awk version) to avoid these file name issues, but the point of my answer isn't to write a complete script for you, it's to show you some of the possible directions you could take to solve it yourself.

---

Another, more complicated alternative is to use perl and one of several perl modules for determining a file's mime type - e.g. [File::Type](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Type) or [File::MimeInfo](https://metacpan.org/release/File-MimeInfo).

Because none of this would be in shell, you wouldn't have any shell quoting or word-splitting issues with filenames (i.e. filenames could contain any valid character without a problem).  This wouldn't be much more work or more difficult than using `file` with awk or shell.

If you wanted to go even further down the perl rabbit hole, perl also has excellent libraries for working with multi-media file metadata - e.g. [Image::Exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) (which works with a lot more than just image files, don't be fooled by the name) or [Video::Info](https://metacpan.org/release/Video-Info) or [Audio::File](https://metacpan.org/release/Audio-File).

Perl even has interfaces to external audio or video processing tools and C libraries.   Libraries with similar capabilities are also available for python.  This would be a lot more work than a quick-and-dirty script that just figures out what kind of file it's dealing with and hands off the actual processing work to other programs, but might be worth the effort if you need to do things like this a lot, or needed to process the files in ways that existing tools don't do or don't do in the way that you need them to.